# Meteor - Meteor.Call inside helper not return value to helper

Tags: javascript, meteor

What is the best way to actually return a value from meteor call in a helper.  I am stumped.  For some reason this and a few other things I have tried isn't working:

```
defaultEmailMsg: function(){
        Meteor.call('getCompanyProfile', companyCode.get(), function (err, res){
            if( res ){
                return res.companyBillingEmailMessage;
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Meteor.call on client runs within Fibers and you cannot return a value to parent from a callback.